# Energetics of a Discus Throw

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia

When a discus thrower releases the discus, the discus will have a certain forward speed that will be the same as the thrower's rotational speed multiplied by the distance between the thrower's center of rotation and the discus.
The last thing that touches the discus is the thrower's index finger. This causes the discus to rotate in a clockwise direction (for a right handed thrower).

The discus used by men weighs $2$ kg with diameter $22$ cm. The women's discus weighs $1$ kg with a diameter of $18$ cm. The simplest discus consists of a circular metal rim, two discs, and a metal center with screws that hold the discus together. A quantity called "rim weight" is the percentage of the discus' weight that is made up by the rim. Rim weights of $50$-$60$% are called center weighted, $60$-$75$% are called low spin, $75$-$90$% are called high spin, and any above that is called something like "ultra high spin".

It'll be easier to get a center weighted disc to spin than an ultrahigh spin discus. Once spinning, it is quite possible that the loss of spin for the highest moment of inertia will be less than for a center weighted disc.
The gyroscopic action will help a rotating, high moment of inertia discus maintain its [attitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(geometry)) and help with its aero foil behavior.
The frictional force required to get a high moment of inertia disc spinning off the index finger without slipping will be greater than for a center weighted disc.

If the distance from the thrower's spine (center of rotation) to the thrower's finger tip is $100$ cm then the released discus will be rotating $100/11 = 9$ times faster than the thrower's arm. The best athletes release the discus at about $30$ m/sec. Using the gearing analogy, this means the discus is rotating at about $45$ revs/sec. This represents a huge spike in rotational energy.
I hope that some enthusiasts will have followed this line of reasoning and can help explain what exactly is going on when a discus is thrown.

Comment: Welcome Andre71. I must say that I find your question a bit peculiar: most of it is a detailed description of the dynamics of discus throwing, but you haven't asked any specific question about it. Are you just looking here for a review of your description?